# SSIS Package not updating modified date on Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have a SSIS Package that looks at a template designed in Excel ( 95 - 2003 worksheet)

Copies that template to a new location. (File System Task)
Populates that copied Template using OLE DB Source to Excel Destination.

[[image: SSIS Package]

[[image: Populating Template File]

All works great. Except the customer has noticed that when the new excel is received, the modified date is the templates last modified date.

I have three other packages that do something similar and their modified date is when the package has been run.

I have done the usual compare properties, but cannot see anything different.
I have also recreated the template from scratch, just in case it was this. No luck..

Any ideas?

Working on :

SQL Server 2014, Visual Studios 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found when the excel file was being put into the process empty, because it was not adding data into the excel file, it was not classing it as modified.
Thus the original modified date being kept!